# Implementing undo in a state-machine based application

Tags: software-design, state-machine, undo

I have an application whose core design is based on a state machine that uses one-way transitions.
This design works well for most scenarios and required features; however the application requires an additional "undo" feature that is available during some of the states. Since many states can have transitions to a single state, this undo feature forces me to keep track of the previous state. To go back to the previous state, I can either:

1. force the previous state that I kept, regardless of existing transitions
   or:
2. create many new "undo" transitions to previous states, and choose the correct undo transition according to the previous state

As I currently see it, both options somewhat break the state machine concept. The second option is less violent but perhaps more clumsy in an "if-else" matter and more vulnerable to bugs.

Which option do you think is preferable? I would love to hear other ideas if you have any.

I am currently using the second suggested method, but it's quite ugly and requires some maintenance

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you to check CQRS + Event Sourcing patterns. It is definitely allows you to implement undo feature but of course it requires you to rethink you actual logic. Another good thing about this approach that it allows you implement a "time-travel" functionality as well.